# Apache tomcat 6 and IIS 7 on port 80 onto same machine

Tags: apache, tomcat, iis-7

Can any one help me regarding my issue? I have 2 IP addresses into my windows server 2008, And I want to bind ip1 for port 80 IIS 7 and ip2 for apache tomcat 6.